# BufferedWriter only write if not written before

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I'm making a configuration class. I want it to write only if the BufferedWriter has not written to the name. If it has written to the name it updates that value. I'm not sure how to do this. Here is my write function so far.

```
    public void setString(String name, String value) {
         try {
             bufferedWriter.write(name + ": " + value);
             bufferedWriter.newLine();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         } 
     }
```

Comment: If it's not a big file, maybe keep a map and overwrite the whole thing.

Comment: Seems like a java.util.Properties would be better for this.

Comment: This is not a job for `BufferedWriter`. A `Writer` can't go back and change lines it had written. It can only append. +1 properties.

Comment: you have to read it and check. or simply overwrite the whole thing

Answer (score 1):

```
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    InputStream input = null;
    boolean exist = false;
    try {
    input = new FileInputStream("config.properties");
    //loading the property file
    prop.load(input);
    // checking if the property exist
    exist = prop.getProperty("name")==null ? false : true;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    if(!exist){
    //then write to the file.
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
    output = new FileOutputStream("config.properties");
    prop.setProperty("name", "yourname");
    //saving the property to the file
    prop.store(output, null);
    } catch (IOException io) {
    io.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
```

since you are making a `configuration` class you can use `Properties` in java to do this.
you can load the `properties` file and check if the data exist with above approach and if it doesnt then you can write the data.

Comment: yeah i noticed,  sorry for that